# SVGs in Chrome sometimes don't render

Tags: google-chrome, svg

THIRD EDIT: here's a working test case. It looks like it has something to do with caching the svg spritesheet. If I configure cache control on my server so that there's no caching of the SVG, the behavior occurs. Feel free to view source (it's all in the one file, but I don't want to include it all here).

https://stuff.spherical.fish/svgtest.html

SECOND EDIT: The fix listed below (directly injecting the  elements in the index.html instead of using an external spritesheet) just stopped working in Chrome v49 (which my beta channel browser just updated to). v48 has the intermittent rendering issue, but v49 pretty consistently doesn't render *anything* that's referred follows a `<svg><use></use></svg>` pattern; but only in a big, complicated angular page. A boring simple test case works fine. Added a bounty for anyone who can directly point me at a known issue or wherever this might be coming from. It is most assuredly not file-not-found, as it's still an intermittent bug, and the whole page renders just fine in firefox and safari.

EDIT: this definitely has something to do with referring to an external resource. When I embed the SVGs directly in index.html and refer to them in with `<use xlink:href="#id"></use>` they work fine, but if I refer to an external file in the `<use>` element, they only load sometimes.

I have some weird behavior in chrome (only - this doesn't happen on opera, firefox, safari); I've been seeing it since at least the early 40s, version-wise.

My behavior is in the middle of an ng-repeated angular structure. Everything is the same - there's a bunch of divs flexboxed together. There's also an SVG element that looks like:

```
<svg class="icon-3">
  <use xlink:href="/assets/trellis-icons.svg#icon-users"></use>
</svg>
```

pretty straightforward.

The thing is, for *some* of these repeated elements, the icon doesn't render. Inspecting the element in the chrome dev tools indicates that the rendered SVG's `<use>` element has a height and width, whereas the non-rendered one has a zero height and width.

It's not like there's any real difference here; I've even manually edited the DOM to make one of the offending entries match one of the rendered ones completely, but the svg still doesn't render. Here's a relevant screenshot.

[image: strange svg render issue]

You can see below (and ignore my padding issues with the button) the first row doesn't have the little heads and word bubble icons. This is an intermittent problem - if I reload the page, it may be fine, or maybe none of the icons will load.

I'm wondering: is there some kind of obscure issue associated with using sprite sheets (all the SVGs that exhibit this behavior are in the same big SVG file and are referenced by #id) loading asynchronously or something?

If this is really unknown / new behavior, I'll work on engineering a test case, but building something that probably relies on some kind of concurrency bug is kind of hard. So I figured I'd ask around first.

EDIT to add: This behavior does not happen if I export the individual svg out as a standalone and use it in an `<img src="icon.svg">` fashion. It does still fail if I do an svg use on the icon in a single standalone file.

EDIT: per @kaiido's request, here is the relevant svg in question.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- thirty other symbols snipped -->
  <symbol id="icon-users" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="m352 397c-15-16-78-32-109-48c-21-11-32-33-32-53c0-10 7-19 13-26c5-6 9-14 13-24c8-4 18-12 18-31c0-12-2-19-5-24c1-11 2-22 3-34c4-45-42-90-89-90c-47 0-92 45-88 90c1 12 2 23 3 34c-4 5-5 12-5 24c0 19 9 27 18 31c4 10 8 18 13 24c6 7 13 16 13 26c0 20-11 42-32 53c-18 9-48 19-72 28l0 68l354 0c0 0 0-32-16-48z m146-7c-21-8-46-16-62-24c-17-8-25-27-25-43c0-8 5-15 10-21c4-5 8-12 11-20c7-3 15-10 15-25c0-10-2-16-5-20c1-9 2-18 3-27c3-37-34-76-73-76c-38 0-75 39-72 76c1 9 2 18 3 27c-3 4-5 10-5 20c0 16 8 22 15 25c3 8 7 15 11 20c4 6 10 13 10 21c0 10-4 22-11 31c30 11 43 22 53 33c19 19 19 58 19 58l103 0z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Any errors or similar in the console? bug like this existed a while back, fix was to use <use ... ></use> instead of <use ... />. Try messing around with absolute URI's and tag formatting, seems like a pretty weird bug though. Maybe submit a ticket? also are you testing on a local machine or on a remote server and does it exist in firefox / IE?

Comment: no errors on the console, I'm using <use></use>. testing on localhost and remote server, bug only happens in chrome: ff, safari both work (not testing on IE/edge/opera). Feels kind of like a concurrency bug - it's usually only the first items in the list that would render which don't, like if you try to use an svg that's not loaded yet you get nothing. I'll fiddle with trying absolute URIs.

Comment: small update - absolute URLs didn't help, neither did cutting out all the cruft in my svg sprite list. (I had originally just imported a big ol' file for dev work, but only actually used 10% of the symbols in there). Still intermittent (clicking around in the angular app in a way that causes the DOM tree to mutate will end up with the icons suddenly rendering).

Comment: Could you show us the markup of `trellis-icons.svg` ? and sepcifically the `#icon-users` element ? If this element itself needs some other element to be rendered, it won't pass. Blink is like really buggy with `xlink:href` and `<funcIRI>` *(for me it even does sound like BrokenLink)*

Comment: @kaiido, I edited to include the file (snipped though, there's a bunch of other icons in there). It's definitely not broken-link, since the SVG does render most of the time. It's just occasionally that it fails to render. It's the same icon (people silhouette) all up and down the list (like in the screenshot), it's just that on a small percentage of the elements, it doesn't render and the inline <use> reports that it is 0x0 px instead of the icon's actual size.

Comment: That issue is not Angular related. We have the exact same problem on our side (the site is not a SPA). A lot of svg icons (~190... yup) and the same randomness

Comment: You really should share your code. It is mentioned that "A boring simple test case works fine". What is the difference between a "boring" test case and the actual (buggy) code? Help people help you...

Comment: Not really sure what would help, @mef. Would you like the 5k+ lines of javascript that make this (not ready to open-source) angular CMS? Take these points on faith, I guess: (1) the icons sometimes load in fine (e.g., it's not a 404 on the resource). (2) the ng-repeat angular construct means the two DOM trees in the screenshot above are _identical_. In one, the icons loaded, and in the other, they didn't. (3) Refreshing the page or clicking around sometimes makes the icons come back. (4) chrome-only. It's quite likely a chrome bug, and this SO question is for help finding which one it is.

Comment: Doctor must see the patient in order to make a diagnostic and cure him. You should do one of the following: 1) make the effort to [create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by extracting the relevant elements out of your apparently monolitic code and sharing them, or 2) hire a consultant.

Comment: @pfooti How do you add a Cache-Control header to your SVG spritesheet?

Comment: @AliF50 it has to be done on the server, a config setting for either nginx or apache or whatever you're serving.

Comment: @pfooti so there is no solution for a local server (i.e. localhost)?

Comment: it is possible to configure your local server to add those headers, it depends on what you're using to serve those files up.

Comment: Is there any update on this now?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it turns out this is a chrome bug after all, and pretty much what I had thought it was: changing `<use>` elements around breaks under certain circumstances. Those circumstances are basically: when the svg spritesheet isn't cached in the browser.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580809

Fixed in canary (M50), might get merged in to M49.

The workaround is to set a cache-control header on the SVG spritesheet that is more than zero. That also helps explain why I only saw this bug in my testing server and not in production - I have different cache settings on my beta box.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this this is still a bug? I seem to experience the exact same thing in Chrome v. 50.0.2661.102 m.
I have a wordpress site were i experience the issue regularly. The .htaccess has the cache header set as such:
<FilesMatch "\.(svg)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

The weird thing is that I also have an .NET Umbraco site that uses SVG sprite sheets the exact same way, but here I experience no issues.

Comment: Myself and a couple of others have still been seeing this problem, in the current version of Chrome (~ v54, v55). It doesn't seem to be the exact same bug, Google notes in the linked bug above that their tests are not failing (although that doesn't guarantee it isn't the same bug and the tests aren't accurate.) It's a bit maddening.

Comment: This issue still exists on chrome 63.

Comment: Yeah, I just recently started noticing this bug again on a dev server (just a simple express server- sometimes the icons won't render). I've taken to injecting all my svgs into index.html. You can actually put them in the `<html>` part of the page, before the `<head>` even - I do this because I later use a `<base href="/">`, for hashless routing and it seems like that base directive only applies to elements physically below it in the html page. So anyway, this way I can just `<use href="#icon-foo">`. More annoying build process to make sure everything's there, but it works.

Comment: Still exists on Chrome 84.0.4136.7

Comment: It seems finally solved in versions 85 and 86. Tested with chrome beta and chrome dev, without workaround for the cache and without the need for direct embedding of the svg in the html page.

Answer (score 6):

Attribute `xlink:href` is deprecated since SVG 2 ([proof link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href)).
New versions of Chrome work strange with this attribute.

If you use `xlink:href` (for ancient browsers) and `href` (for new browsers)
everything will work fine everywhere.

Comment: FWIW, this was a chrome bug from quite some time ago (version 48) associated with chrome not properly using resources that did not have a cache-control header.

Comment: This bug is sometimes reproduced on a Chrome 62 and Single Page Application (Angular 1.6). If content is loaded dynamically and contains SVG images.

Comment: Yea, I have the same issue on chrome 63. A year ago, the bug existed. Now it still exists.

Comment: Are you saying using just `xlink:href` causes the issue, but using both does not? Because that seems to work for me, at least for now. As far as I can tell, Safari is the only browser that doesn't support `xlink:href` for recent versions, including the latest.

Answer (score 4):

I had this bug too. Was fixed with pfooti solution by caching & then by the webkit update.

But later it came back: wasn't the same thing, but could be useful for other, later.

I opened my SVG with Inkscape (but the same works in Illustrator, too), selected my object and applied `path` > `union`, and saved:

`<path class="st0" d="M32 272l128 48 16 160 80-112 112 112L480 32 32 272zm318.7 145.4L256 320l128-176-192 153.8-82.6-31 322-172.5-80.7 323.1z"/>`

became

`<path d="M480 32L32 272l128 48 16 160 80-112 112 112L480 32zm-48.6 62.3l-80.7 323.1L256 320l128-176-192 153.8-82.6-31 322-172.5z"/>`

And now it works!

I don't know exactly why, but Chrome seems to have some issue with the first syntax.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried to do the same through Adobe Illustrator (object - disassemble). The svg looks fine visually, but the draw animation stops working.