# Referencing an external svg file with <use> tag doesn't work

Tags: html, svg

The below svg (created using some online service) is saved in a file (called `arrows.svg`) which i'm trying to reference from an html file using the `<use>` tag:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" 
     width="128" height="128">
   <defs>
      <path id="b7a1Gm7TF" d="M7.41 190C7.41 173.43 20.53 160 36.72 160C66.02 160 212.55 160 476.29 160C476.29 124 476.29 104 476.29 100C476.29 73.29 507.92 59.95 526.32 78.79C536.09 88.79 614.24 168.79 624 178.79C635.45 190.51 635.45 209.5 624 221.22C614.24 231.22 536.09 311.22 526.32 321.22C507.99 339.98 476.29 326.82 476.29 300C476.29 296 476.29 276 476.29 240C212.55 240 66.02 240 36.72 240C20.53 240 7.41 226.57 7.41 210C7.41 206 7.41 192 7.41 190ZM163.71 400C163.71 364 163.71 344 163.71 340C163.71 313.36 132.13 299.9 113.68 318.79C103.91 328.79 25.76 408.79 16 418.79C4.55 430.51 4.55 449.5 16 461.22C25.76 471.22 103.91 551.22 113.68 561.22C132.03 580 163.71 566.8 163.71 540C163.71 536 163.71 516 163.71 480C427.45 480 573.98 480 603.28 480C619.47 480 632.59 466.57 632.59 450C632.59 448 632.59 432 632.59 430C632.59 413.43 619.47 400 603.28 400C544.67 400 398.15 400 163.71 400Z"></path>
   </defs>
   <g>
      <g>
         <g>
            <use xlink:href="#b7a1Gm7TF" opacity="1" fill="#168d2b" fill-opacity="1"></use>
         </g>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

I know that referencing an external svg file requires specifying the referenced `id`, but no matter where I add the `id` attribute, referencing it doesn't work (using it inlined does work, as shown above).

Here's `index.html` (note that I'm [using `href` instead of `xlink:href`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47332915/3002584)):

```
<svg>
    <use href="arrows.svg#arrows"></use>
</svg>
```

`arrows.svg` - 1st trial:

```
...
   <svg id="arrows" ...></svg>
...
```

`arrows.svg` - 2nd trial:

```
...
    <g>
       <use id="arrows" xlink:href="#b7a1Gm7TF" ...></use>
    </g>
...
```

EDIT:

However, when I simplify the svg as follows, adding the `id` upon the `<svg>` tag, referencing svg file works as expected:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="arrows" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" 
     width="128" height="128" opacity="1" fill="#168d2b" fill-opacity="1">
   <path id="b7a1Gm7TF" d="M7.41 190C7.41 173.43 20.53 160 36.72 160C66.02 160 212.55 160 476.29 160C476.29 124 476.29 104 476.29 100C476.29 73.29 507.92 59.95 526.32 78.79C536.09 88.79 614.24 168.79 624 178.79C635.45 190.51 635.45 209.5 624 221.22C614.24 231.22 536.09 311.22 526.32 321.22C507.99 339.98 476.29 326.82 476.29 300C476.29 296 476.29 276 476.29 240C212.55 240 66.02 240 36.72 240C20.53 240 7.41 226.57 7.41 210C7.41 206 7.41 192 7.41 190ZM163.71 400C163.71 364 163.71 344 163.71 340C163.71 313.36 132.13 299.9 113.68 318.79C103.91 328.79 25.76 408.79 16 418.79C4.55 430.51 4.55 449.5 16 461.22C25.76 471.22 103.91 551.22 113.68 561.22C132.03 580 163.71 566.8 163.71 540C163.71 536 163.71 516 163.71 480C427.45 480 573.98 480 603.28 480C619.47 480 632.59 466.57 632.59 450C632.59 448 632.59 432 632.59 430C632.59 413.43 619.47 400 603.28 400C544.67 400 398.15 400 163.71 400Z"></path>
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong with the first, more complex-structrued svg version?

Note that in reality, the svg file can be much more complex than that, and I can't be sure I'd be able to simplify it the way I did here.

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox supports this, not sure about other browsers. You are serving these files from a web server and not direct from your file system aren't you?

Comment: @RobertLongson, I tried it on Chrome 81, Firefox 75, Edge, it works in niether of them.

Comment: @RobertLongson, BTW, referencing a simply-structured svg works. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41809317/3002584) works for me (tried it on Chrome).

Comment: Here's a [working example](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/struct-use-05-b.html) that displays correctly for me in Firefox. It contains external <use> references.

Comment: @RobertLongson, see my edit, might be a clue?